# Making Timeline in qliksense

Tags: bar-chart, qliksense

I would like to display a timeline in qlik sense using the  Bar Chart Object [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNYl.jpg)as follows:
The x-axis represented the months of the year.
The Y-axis represented the years.
The length of the graph will be a date range in the appropriate year and month.
It will look like this:

[exaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyNYl.jpg)

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a Pivot Table chart object with a background colour expression set to yellow.

In this example, I calculated the day number of the start date and the duration of the period to be shown in yellow.
The Bar Chart shows the sum of 'DayNumberStartDate' and 'Duration'

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzC8t.png)

Comment: I would want to do it with Bar chart. Do you have any idea? Thanks